# how to monitor topic, when a certain topic not exist?

Tags: ros, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to do a such thing : To  monitor a topic .
When everything is OK, a certain topic is always published by node A at a rate. when something wrong ,the node A is died,and the  topic does  not exist .At this time ,how can i know this topic  exist or not ?

Does ROS has  such API to monitor a topic ,when it does not exist ,notify me and i can use this signal  to do something i want.

Any suggestions will be appreciated ,thank you  very much !!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246654/how-to-monitor-topic,--when-a-certain-topic--not--exist?/) by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2016-10-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The subscriber knows to how many publishers it is connected to:
[getNumPublishers](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1Subscriber.html)
Or you use rospy to directly get a list of published topics: [get_published_topics](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/rospy/html/rospy-module.html#get_published_topics).

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on 2016-11-01**:
Wow!  I learn something new every day!  Sorry about giving a completely wrong answer!

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2016-11-09**:
Thanks a lot ~~